# How can I find the slope at Vout/Vin at Vin = 0, from the datasheet about Op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I'm trying OpenModelica and I'm going to simulate an Op-amp.

(No it's not Windows 95, it's IceWM + Ubuntu 20.04)
[image]

But I wonder where I can find the slope Vout/Vin when Vin = 0 in the datahseet?
I have heard that the slope from an Op-amp is so large so not even the datasheet write it out. Is that true? Or can I find it?

Assume that we are using this datasheet:
https://www.mouser.se/datasheet/2/389/cd00001046-1795623.pdf

Comment: *Is that true?* - is it true that you have heard it - you may have heard this but it's untrue.

Comment: @Andyaka So why does OpenModelica ask about it?

Comment: *I have heard that the slope from an Op-amp is so large so not even the datasheet write it out.* That's pure **nonsense**, **writing** a large number is easy. Next time, when in doubt, immediately ask **WHY?**. That should help detecting BS like this. Anyway, the term "slope" is confusing as it often refers to change of a signal over time. Vout/Vin (at Vin = 0) is simply the (small signal) gain. Which is listed in every opamp's datasheet.

Comment: Please see this: https://youtu.be/7FYHt5XviKc?t=163

Comment: Most of us (including me) have seen Dave's video already, I think that the chance that you misunderstood Dave's story is much more likely than Dave telling nonsense. Dave's audience consists of beginners but also many old-farts (like myself) who will **immediately** point out any mistakes. So you can assume what Dave says is not nonsense.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson your software needs that value but it's completely untrue that *the slope from an Op-amp is so large so not even the datasheet write it out*. It appears in every op-amp data sheet I've ever read.

Comment: Dave says that you can **think of** that gain being "infinitely large", he means, you do not need to consider that gain, it is always large enough (for practical purposes). And when it is not, you're not using the opamp correctly.

Comment: It's called "open loop gain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the large signal voltage gain Avd in the datasheet. 100,000 typical (under the specified conditions).

Also refer to figures 17 and 19 for typical behavior under different conditions.

Comment: So "Large voltage gain: 100 dB" in the datasheet is the gain Vout/Vin at Vin = 0?

Comment: Look carefully, there is no 100 dB anywhere in the datasheet. It is \$A_{vd}\$ = 100 V/mV which is the same as 100 000 V/V or a factor 100 000.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 100 dB is quoted on page 1 and 100 dB = 100,000 V/V.

Comment: About figures 17 and 19. What should I look at? Large voltage gain, is that the gain when I'm exceeding the maximum or minimum voltage?

Comment: They show you how the gain typically varies with temperature and supply voltage. The gain of 100,000 is only at one specific supply voltage and temperature.